# Почему не полностью выключается ноутбук (Dell Vostro 5470)?

Tags: windows-10, железо, dell

После достаточно длительной работы на ноуте, он ИНОГДА не полностью выключается.
А именно: кнопка POWER продолжает гореть, индикатор питания продолжает гореть (на скрине видно), иногда слышно активация охлаждения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модель ноута:
Dell vostro 5470
**Windows 10 Pro 64** (к стати эти проблемы были замечены после обновления с 8.1 на 10)
Все драйвера обновлены.

Comment: Win+R -> cmd -> shutdown -s -t 0 что делает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а вы его точно выключаете? может это длительный переход в режим гибернации?

На всякий случай проверьте состояния функций, что выполняются в фоне:

1. обновления системы
2. проверки антивируса
3. дефрагментация
4. индексация файлов на жестком диске
5. Правильность установки драйверов (Windows 10 не всегда нормально работает с Wi-Fi адаптерами Broadcom)

Comment: Ну я точно нажимаю выключить) А что дальше происходит - хз. Вообще поначалу мне очень понравилась Форточка 10, но чем дальше, тем больше разочаровываюсь.

Comment: Процесс завершение работы состоит из многих шагов, самый медленный из которых - завершение работы системных служб. Может у Вас установлен какой-то злой sql сервер или что-то типа того? Так же может быть установлена проверка жесткого диска при выключении. Проверьте все что я указал выше

Comment: как же проверить?

Comment: @AndreyAHAHAC зайдите в администрирование компьютера, проверьте службы, что запускаются при старте системы и вырубаются при завершении работы. Проверки жесткого диска - в свойствах самого диска (как с системой так и без нее)